# Processmaker could not find PHP executor in PM4

Tags: php, processmaker, processmaker-api

I'm encountering an error using the PHP executor, specifically the community version. The provided image displays the error message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y98VY.png). I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think there was enough code but it was an image so it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess at your error if it is the same version as mine.
The Executors are created on demand by the app, if you run them without creating the executors you get and error saying the docker image is not found.

You can either go into the admin pages, go to executors, go to the one that you need and there is a build and save button. When you press it it will build the image. You need to do this once then the executor will work.

There is another way to do this via the command line.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/processmaker/configuration/install-script-executors/ is a better expliantion.